# What does PolynomialQuotientRemainder really mean for rational functions?

Tags: polynomials

When I type this command in mathematica:

```
PolynomialQuotientRemainder[x^2 - 1, (x - 2)/(x + 2), x]
```

It returns:

```
{4 + 4 x + x^2, 3}
```

However, there is no relation like $f = gq + r$ satisfy. So what does PolynomialQuotientRemainder mean for rational functions?

Comment: Would the result of `(x^2 - 1)/((x - 2)/(x + 2)) == 4 + 4 x + x^2 + 3/((x - 2)/(x + 2)) // Simplify` help?

Comment: @J.M. I just want to know the meaning of this function. Your method is correct of course, however I don't know why this function support rational functions as parameters.

Comment: I voted to close this because, well, `f` does equal `q*g+r`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on comment by J.M.,

```
p = x^2 - 1;
q = (x - 2)/(x + 2);

{g, r} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[p, q, x]

(*  {4 + 4 x + x^2, 3}  *)

p == g*q + r // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```